# Make dictionary with 2 keys referring to the one value

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I want to have a dictionary (or data structure that supports this) that can access a value under two keys, however when you .pop() the value using one key, it will also pop the other item.

- Only two of the same item can be present within the entire dictionary
- The items are within different lists. Lists are accessed via a key
- Removal of both items must be O(1) (as if simply using `.pop()`)

My attempt:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Value:
    def __init__(self, v=None):
        self.v = v

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.v)

list_of_words = ['barrd', 'laary', 'grrup']
words = defaultdict(list)

for word in list_of_words:
    temp_word = Value(word)
    words[word[1:2]+'P'].append(temp_word)
    words[word[-2:-1]+'S'].append(temp_word)


print(words)
current = 'baard'
print(words[current[-2:-1]+'P'].pop())
print(words)
```

Actual output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'aP': [barrd, laary], 'rS': [barrd, laary], 'rP': [grrup], 'uS': [grrup]})
grrup
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'aP': [barrd, laary], 'rS': [barrd, laary], 'rP': [], 'uS': [grrup]})
```

Desired Output: ('grrup' removed from both key locations)

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'aP': [barrd, laary], 'rS': [barrd, laary], 'rP': [grrup], 'uS': [grrup]})
grrup
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'aP': [barrd, laary], 'rS': [barrd, laary], 'rP': [], 'uS': []})
```

Simplified Example:

```
d = {'a': [10, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 10]}
d.pop('b') # pop's 10 from key 'b', also removing it from 'a'
d = {'a': [2, 3], 'b': [2]}
```

Comment: Shall this datastructure have an interface that behaves like `dict`?

Comment: Simplified example then.... `{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 3]}` does `pop`ing the value of `2` result in `{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [3]}` or something else? What about duplicated values for the same key, does popping them just remove one instance or all instances? It'd help if you could provide some simpler example input/output in your post.

Comment: @JonClements The results you have provided would be correct. Okay I will update it now.

Comment: Also... what about cases such as: `data = [1, 2]; d = {'a': data, 'b': data}`... ? Is it guaranteed or should be such that your values are always lists?

Comment: It should be that the values are always lists. As I am adding values with .append() and "removing" values with .pop()

Comment: @LutzHorn Ideally yes. However if there is a simpler way to go about this without following the `dict` interface, then that would help too!

Comment: _"Removal of both items must be O(1)"_ You can't really remove an item from a list in O(1) time.

Comment: Your simplified example is not consistent with you constraints: how could you remove 10 in O(1) from `d[a]`

Comment: My question is for a data structure that would be able to do that. I know you can remove it in slower time. I am therefore wondering if you can somehow pair these items, or use a mapping of multiple dictionaries to achieve O(1) in removal

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
from collections import defaultdict

class MyDataStructure(defaultdict):
    def mypop(self, value):
        for key in self:
            self[key] = [i for i in self[key] if str(i) != str(value)]
        return self

class Value:
    def __init__(self, v=None):
        self.v = v

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.v)

list_of_words = ['barrd', 'laary', 'grrup']
words = MyDataStructure(list)
# pdb.set_trace()

for word in list_of_words:
    temp_word = Value(word)
    # second letter + P
    words[word[1:2] + 'P'].append(temp_word)
    # second last letter + S
    words[word[-2:-1] + 'S'].append(temp_word)

print(words)
current = 'barrd'
words.mypop(current)
print(words)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'aP': [barrd, laary], 'rS': [barrd, laary], 'rP': [grrup], 'uS': [grrup]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'aP': [laary], 'rS': [laary], 'rP': [grrup], 'uS': [grrup]})
```